# Wanting Tabled Report of Missing/Non-Missing Values

Tags: sas

I have a data set with a number of records (the contents of which are irrelevant) and a series of flag variables at the end of each record. Something like this:

```
Record ID   Flag 1   Flag 2   Flag 3
1           Y
2                    Y        Y
3
4
5
6           Y        Y
```

I would like to create a printed report (or, ideally, a data set that I could then print) that would look something like the following:

```
Variable   N    % Not Missing
Flag 1     6    33.33333
Flag 2     6    33.33333
Flag 3     6    16.66666
```

I can accomplish something close to what I want for one variable at a time using Proc Freq with something like this:

```
proc freq data=Work.Records noprint;
    tables Flag1 /out=Work.Temp;
run;
```

I suppose I could easily write a macro to loop through each variable and concatenate the results into one data set... but that seems WAY too complex for this. There has to be a built-in SAS procedure for this, but I'm not finding it.

Any thoughts out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the fabulous world of Proc Tabulate.

`PROC TABULATE` is the procedure to use when `PROC FREQ` can't cut it.  It works similarly to `PROC FREQ` in that it has table statements, but beyond that it's pretty much on steroids.

```
data test;
input RecordID   (Flag1   Flag2   Flag3) ($);
datalines;
1 Y . .
2 . Y Y
3 . . .
4 . . .
5 . . .
6 . Y Y
;;;;
run;
proc tabulate data=test;
class flag1-flag3/missing;
tables (flag1-flag3),colpctn;  *things that generate rows,things that generate columns;
run;
```

Unfortunately it's not easy to hide the blank rows without using some advanced style tricks, but if you don't mind seeing both rows this works pretty well.